# Why is nullable decimal crashing my object initializer?

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net

I have an object called Project.

In Project I have a property definition like this:

```
public decimal? FyTotalCost { get; set; }
```

Then I roll through a datareader to fill a list of objects.

```
while (dr.Read())
                {
                    #region Fill Project object
                    try
                    {
                        projects.Add(new Project
                        {
FyTotalCost = (dr["fy_total_cost"] != null
                                                    && dr["fy_total_cost"].ToString() != string.Empty
                                                    && dr["fy_total_cost"].ToString() != "") ?
                                                    decimal.Parse(dr["fy_total_cost"].ToString()) :
                                                    (decimal?)null,
```

This evaluates to false in the quick watcy:

```
dr["fy_total_cost"] != null
                                                    && dr["fy_total_cost"].ToString() != string.Empty
                                                    && dr["fy_total_cost"].ToString() != ""
```

But it seems this is getting executed:

```
decimal.Parse(dr["fy_total_cost"].ToString())
```

instead of this:

```
(decimal?)null
```

I'm trace.writing to the output window:

this is what I get:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in  mscorlib.dll

fy: 

fy_total_cost: 

budget_start_date: 

budget_end_date: 

Error Message: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, 

NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)

at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)

at System.Int32.Parse(String s)

at TransferProjects.Program.FillProjectsModel() in c:\Development\TransferProjects\TransferProjects\Program.cs:line 172
```

Comment: Your code and trace are *really* hard to read. Please put some effort into formatting your question before you post - and ideally, show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: As an aside, `string.Empty` and `""` are the same thing.

Comment: Whatever @JonSkeet said:) - short program would be `var s = "some string"; var r = decimal.Parse(s);` where "some string" is the value of `dr["fy_total_cost"].ToString()`

Answer (score 2):

Because null in the database is actually DBNull.Value. You should be checking for that instead:

`FyTotalCost = (dr["fy_total_cost"] != DBNull.Value` ...

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't a code issue.
I have FY coming back null in a few records and I was trying to use it's value to set BudgetStartDate.
Error was actually cannot convert string to int? something to that affect.
I was wondering why it was complaining about string in wrong format for int? rather than decimal?